# GAE newly created task queues are "disabled" but working?

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

So, I've created a couple new task queues on my GAE project. However these task queues have showed as "Disabled" ever since I created them. It doesn't seem to matter how many times I deploy the queue.yaml file or in which module the queue.yaml resides.

However, the queues appear to be working correctly. I can push new tasks to them, they show correct stats, and the tasks are being executed properly.

[Task Queue Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KXRu.png)

The relevant sections of my queue.yaml are here:

```
- name: thumbnails
  rate: 10/h
  bucket_size: 5
  max_concurrent_requests: 2
  target: api
  retry_parameters:
    task_retry_limit: 10
    min_backoff_seconds: 3600
    max_backoff_seconds: 14400
    max_doublings: 3

- name: parser
  rate: 1/m
  bucket_size: 5
  max_concurrent_requests: 2
  target: api
  retry_parameters:
    task_retry_limit: 2
    min_backoff_seconds: 600
    max_backoff_seconds: 1800
    max_doublings: 3
```

Comment: FWIW `queue.yaml` is an *app-level* config, not a *module* config. It always applies to the `default` module (even though individual tasks may be directed to specific modules).

Comment: I take it you just have 1 queue.yaml file in your project root?

Comment: And have you tried pulling all the configuration except the absolute minimum? Are these the only 2 queues with this behaviour? Are there other queues that work OK?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that there is only one queue.yaml file that is applicable to the project, not individual modules. I was merely testing behaviors with the modules. And All of my other queues are working perfectly. These are the only two that show as 'disabled'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the rate for the Queue is less than or equal to 1/m it will display as disabled even though it still works. There is an open [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12282) for this, I would recommend 'staring' the issue to get updates.

Comment: This looks to be exactly what I have been looking for. According to that thread, it would make sense that these queues with lower execution rates are the only ones showing as 'disabled'.